# Karma-Jasmine unit test syntax

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Can you have multiple `describe()` in the same `.spec.ts` file? I am not talking about nested `describe` here.

```
describe('First describe', () => {
  it();
 })
describe('Second describe', () => {
it();
});
```

Is there any risk in doing this at any point in running the tests? I currently have 4 `describe` in my `.spec` to test different scenarios. Most of the time all tests pass. But some tests fail randomly even though the expected value is correct. Could the multiple `describe` be causing some issue? Is it better to make it nested? This is for an `angular4` app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add multiple `describe()` in the `.spec.ts` because it is just javascript function. But for finding fails in your tests you need to debug it.

You can find it by following next link:
[https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-It's_Just_Functions](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-It%27s_Just_Functions)

Comment: I completely missed that in the docs, thanks! What is the best way to debug unit tests? Is there a specific package I need to use ?

Comment: I use standart `console.log` and `debugger` for this.